# Footer goes out of the container

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a fixed footer with bottom: 0. My container has a max-width of 1264px. 
When I'm trying to make a fixed footer at the bottom of my screen, it goes out of the container but only in the right side.

Codepen:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/NMYxam

```css
/*CSS PENTRU INDEX.HTML*/
/*CSS PENTRU INDEX.HTML*/
/*CSS PENTRU INDEX.HTML*/
/*CSS PENTRU INDEX.HTML*/
/*CSS PENTRU INDEX.HTML*/

body {
    width: 100%;
    text-rendering: optimizeLegibility; /*setam textul sa fie optimzat pentru o lizbilitate mai buna, in detrimentul vitezei de incarcare si a preciziei geometrice*/
    font-weight: 200;
    font-size: 15px;
    overflow: hidden; /*dezactivam scrollbar-urile in cazul in care continutul depaseste "element's box"*/
    font-family: 'Proxima Nova';
    color: #fff;
    height: 100%;
}

@keyframes tranzitie-inceput {
    from {opacity: 0;}
    to {opacity: 1;}
}

#mate, #info {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 5rem;
  text-transform: uppercase; /*transformam textul in MAJUSCULE*/
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #429ba8;
  height: 50%;
  position: relative;
}

#mate {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #D3D3D3; /*inseram un border gri, subtire, ce va avea efectul de umbra/diferentiere a celor 2 jumatati*/
}

#info {
   background-color: #87cebf;
}

#container-index {
    height: 100vh; /*div-ul container va fi egal cu toata inaltimea viewport-ului, ceea ce va face ca continutul sa fie la fel de mare ca suprafata vizibila a device-ului utilizatorului*/
    animation-name: tranzitie-inceput;
    animation-duration: 1s;
    user-select: none; /*dezactivam selectia utilizatorului*/
    cursor: pointer;
}

.text-mate {
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%); /*centram textul VERTICAL in interiorul parintelui #MATE*/
}

.text-info {
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%); /*centram textul VERTICAL in interiorul parintelui #INFO*/
}

.hover { /*pregatim clasa ce se va adauga div-ului peste care trecem cu mouse-ul, utilizand jQuery*/
    transition: 2.5s; /*folosim un efect incet in care elementul se mareste*/
    height: 75% !important;
}

.default { /*pregatim clasa ce se va adauga celuilalt div fata de cel pe care se trece mouse-ul, utilizand jQuery*/
    transition: 1.5s;
    height: 50% !important; /*folosim un efect rapid in care se va ajunge la forma initiala*/
}

.not-hovered-on { /*pregatim clasa ce se va adauga celuilalt div fata de cel pe care se trece mouse-ul, utilizand jQuery*/
    transition: 2.5s; 
    height: 25% !important; /*folosim un efect incet in care elementul se micsoreaza*/
}

/*CSS PENTRU PAGINA-MATE.HTML*/
/*CSS PENTRU PAGINA-MATE.HTML*/
/*CSS PENTRU PAGINA-MATE.HTML*/
/*CSS PENTRU PAGINA-MATE.HTML*/
/*CSS PENTRU PAGINA-MATE.HTML*/
/*CSS PENTRU PAGINA-MATE.HTML*/
/*CSS PENTRU PAGINA-MATE.HTML*/

#container-mate {
    background-color: #e6e7d0;
    height: 100vh; /*div-ul container va fi egal cu toata inaltimea viewport-ului, ceea ce va face ca continutul sa fie la fel de mare ca suprafata vizibila a device-ului utilizatorului*/
}

/*HEADER-UL PAGINII*/

#meniu-mate {
    max-width: 1264px; /*meniul va fi MAXIM 1300px*/
    margin: 0 auto; /*meniul este centrat orizontal*/
    background-color: #fff;
    height: 100vh;
}

.mate-sus {
    height: 15vh; /*15% din viewport*/
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #7ec7bc, #429ba8);
}

.logo {
    float: right;
}

.selector-portal {
    height: 4vh;
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #9bddc5, #34bab8);
    margin-bottom: 2rem;
}

.selector-portal > ul {
        display: inline-block;
        position: relative;
        top: 50%;
        transform: translateY(-50%);
        margin-left: 1.5rem;
        font-size: 1.5rem;
}

.selector-portal > ul > li {
        display: inline;
}

.selector-portal > ul > li > a {
        text-decoration: none;
        color: #fff;
        font-style: italic;  
}

/*CONTINUTUL PAGINII*/

#cursuri-mate {
    height: 15%;
    max-width: 90%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: #429ba8;
    margin-bottom: 3.5rem;
}

.cursuri-text-mate {
    font-size: 4rem;
    position: relative;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    top: 50%;
    margin-left: 4rem;
}

.fa-book {
    color: black;
    position: relative;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    top: 50%;
    float: right;
    margin-right: 2rem;
}

#exercitii-mate {
    height: 15%;
    max-width: 90%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: #429ba8;
    margin-bottom: 3.5rem;
}

.exercitii-text-mate {
    font-size: 4rem;
    position: relative;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    top: 50%;
    margin-left: 4rem;
}

.fa-pencil-alt-mate {
    color: black;
    position: relative;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    top: 50%;
    float: right;
    margin-right: 2rem;
}

.fa-question {
    color: black;
    position: relative;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    top: 50%;
    float: right;
    margin-right: 2rem;
}

#variante-mate {
    height: 15%;
    max-width: 90%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: #429ba8;
    margin-bottom: 3.5rem;
}

.variante-text-mate {
    font-size: 4rem;
    position: relative;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    top: 50%;
    margin-left: 4rem;
}

.fa-pencil-alt {
    color: black;
    position: relative;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    top: 50%;
    float: right;
    margin-right: 2rem;
}

/*FOOTER*/

.mate-jos {
    background-color: #28494e;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
}

.mate-jos-text {
    
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link href="css/reset.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="css/fontawesome-all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <title>Portal Mate</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container-mate">
    <section id="meniu-mate">
        <header class="mate-sus"><h1 class="logo">MATE-INFO || LOGO</h1></header>
        <nav class="selector-portal">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="portal-mate.html">mate</a></li>
                <li><a href="portal-info.html">info</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        <article id="cursuri-mate">
            <i class="fas fa-book fa-6x"></i>
            <h1 class="cursuri-text-mate">Cursuri</h1>
        </article>
        <article id="exercitii-mate">
            <i class="fas fa-pencil-alt fa-6x"></i>
            <h1 class="exercitii-text-mate">Exercitii</h1>               
        </article>
        <article id="variante-mate">
            <i class="fas fa-question fa-6x"></i>
            <h1 class="variante-text-mate">Variante Bacalaureat</h1>
        </article>
        <div id="footer-wrap">
            <footer class="mate-jos">
                <h6 class="mate-jos-text">a</h6>
            </footer>
        </div>
    </section>
</div>
</body>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"
        integrity="sha256-3edrmyuQ0w65f8gfBsqowzjJe2iM6n0nKciPUp8y+7E="
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="js/js.js"></script>
</html>
```

Ideas?
I tried the footer with a wraper with a max-width: 1264px, but it didn't work. There's something I'm missing. 
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Just give the footer the same width as the rest of the content: `.mate-jos { max-width: 1264px; }`

Comment: It doesn't work. I tried to.

Comment: Really? https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xjWREj

Comment: what??? I did that like 3 times and it didn't work. I can't get it wtf? I'm really amazed. Please add that as an answer so I can mark it as correct. I swear I tried it before trying to wrap the footer but somehow it didn't work. I suppose the ctrl+f5 did the trick now.

Comment: @Turnip it's because max-width: 1264px and width: 100%. I used it only with max-width. Why are both needed?

Comment: Without `width: 100%` the element will take up the minimum space that  it can. ie the width of the "a" character.

Comment: Ohhhh. Now I got it. Thanks a lot. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give your `<footer>` a max-width of 1264px so that it matches the rest of your content.

```
.mate-jos { 
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1264px;
}
```

```css
/*CSS PENTRU INDEX.HTML*/
/*CSS PENTRU INDEX.HTML*/
/*CSS PENTRU INDEX.HTML*/
/*CSS PENTRU INDEX.HTML*/
/*CSS PENTRU INDEX.HTML*/

body {
    width: 100%;
    text-rendering: optimizeLegibility; /*setam textul sa fie optimzat pentru o lizbilitate mai buna, in detrimentul vitezei de incarcare si a preciziei geometrice*/
    font-weight: 200;
    font-size: 15px;
    overflow: hidden; /*dezactivam scrollbar-urile in cazul in care continutul depaseste "element's box"*/
    font-family: 'Proxima Nova';
    color: #fff;
    height: 100%;
}

@keyframes tranzitie-inceput {
    from {opacity: 0;}
    to {opacity: 1;}
}

#mate, #info {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 5rem;
  text-transform: uppercase; /*transformam textul in MAJUSCULE*/
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #429ba8;
  height: 50%;
  position: relative;
}

#mate {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #D3D3D3; /*inseram un border gri, subtire, ce va avea efectul de umbra/diferentiere a celor 2 jumatati*/
}

#info {
   background-color: #87cebf;
}

#container-index {
    height: 100vh; /*div-ul container va fi egal cu toata inaltimea viewport-ului, ceea ce va face ca continutul sa fie la fel de mare ca suprafata vizibila a device-ului utilizatorului*/
    animation-name: tranzitie-inceput;
    animation-duration: 1s;
    user-select: none; /*dezactivam selectia utilizatorului*/
    cursor: pointer;
}

.text-mate {
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%); /*centram textul VERTICAL in interiorul parintelui #MATE*/
}

.text-info {
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%); /*centram textul VERTICAL in interiorul parintelui #INFO*/
}

.hover { /*pregatim clasa ce se va adauga div-ului peste care trecem cu mouse-ul, utilizand jQuery*/
    transition: 2.5s; /*folosim un efect incet in care elementul se mareste*/
    height: 75% !important;
}

.default { /*pregatim clasa ce se va adauga celuilalt div fata de cel pe care se trece mouse-ul, utilizand jQuery*/
    transition: 1.5s;
    height: 50% !important; /*folosim un efect rapid in care se va ajunge la forma initiala*/
}

.not-hovered-on { /*pregatim clasa ce se va adauga celuilalt div fata de cel pe care se trece mouse-ul, utilizand jQuery*/
    transition: 2.5s; 
    height: 25% !important; /*folosim un efect incet in care elementul se micsoreaza*/
}

/*CSS PENTRU PAGINA-MATE.HTML*/
/*CSS PENTRU PAGINA-MATE.HTML*/
/*CSS PENTRU PAGINA-MATE.HTML*/
/*CSS PENTRU PAGINA-MATE.HTML*/
/*CSS PENTRU PAGINA-MATE.HTML*/
/*CSS PENTRU PAGINA-MATE.HTML*/
/*CSS PENTRU PAGINA-MATE.HTML*/

#container-mate {
    background-color: #e6e7d0;
    height: 100vh; /*div-ul container va fi egal cu toata inaltimea viewport-ului, ceea ce va face ca continutul sa fie la fel de mare ca suprafata vizibila a device-ului utilizatorului*/
}

/*HEADER-UL PAGINII*/

#meniu-mate {
    max-width: 1264px; /*meniul va fi MAXIM 1300px*/
    margin: 0 auto; /*meniul este centrat orizontal*/
    background-color: #fff;
    height: 100vh;
}

.mate-sus {
    height: 15vh; /*15% din viewport*/
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #7ec7bc, #429ba8);
}

.logo {
    float: right;
}

.selector-portal {
    height: 4vh;
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #9bddc5, #34bab8);
    margin-bottom: 2rem;
}

.selector-portal > ul {
        display: inline-block;
        position: relative;
        top: 50%;
        transform: translateY(-50%);
        margin-left: 1.5rem;
        font-size: 1.5rem;
}

.selector-portal > ul > li {
        display: inline;
}

.selector-portal > ul > li > a {
        text-decoration: none;
        color: #fff;
        font-style: italic;  
}

/*CONTINUTUL PAGINII*/

#cursuri-mate {
    height: 15%;
    max-width: 90%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: #429ba8;
    margin-bottom: 3.5rem;
}

.cursuri-text-mate {
    font-size: 4rem;
    position: relative;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    top: 50%;
    margin-left: 4rem;
}

.fa-book {
    color: black;
    position: relative;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    top: 50%;
    float: right;
    margin-right: 2rem;
}

#exercitii-mate {
    height: 15%;
    max-width: 90%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: #429ba8;
    margin-bottom: 3.5rem;
}

.exercitii-text-mate {
    font-size: 4rem;
    position: relative;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    top: 50%;
    margin-left: 4rem;
}

.fa-pencil-alt-mate {
    color: black;
    position: relative;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    top: 50%;
    float: right;
    margin-right: 2rem;
}

.fa-question {
    color: black;
    position: relative;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    top: 50%;
    float: right;
    margin-right: 2rem;
}

#variante-mate {
    height: 15%;
    max-width: 90%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: #429ba8;
    margin-bottom: 3.5rem;
}

.variante-text-mate {
    font-size: 4rem;
    position: relative;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    top: 50%;
    margin-left: 4rem;
}

.fa-pencil-alt {
    color: black;
    position: relative;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    top: 50%;
    float: right;
    margin-right: 2rem;
}

/*FOOTER*/

.mate-jos {
    background-color: #28494e;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    max-width: 1264px;
}

.mate-jos-text {
    
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link href="css/reset.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="css/fontawesome-all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <title>Portal Mate</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container-mate">
    <section id="meniu-mate">
        <header class="mate-sus"><h1 class="logo">MATE-INFO || LOGO</h1></header>
        <nav class="selector-portal">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="portal-mate.html">mate</a></li>
                <li><a href="portal-info.html">info</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        <article id="cursuri-mate">
            <i class="fas fa-book fa-6x"></i>
            <h1 class="cursuri-text-mate">Cursuri</h1>
        </article>
        <article id="exercitii-mate">
            <i class="fas fa-pencil-alt fa-6x"></i>
            <h1 class="exercitii-text-mate">Exercitii</h1>               
        </article>
        <article id="variante-mate">
            <i class="fas fa-question fa-6x"></i>
            <h1 class="variante-text-mate">Variante Bacalaureat</h1>
        </article>
        <div id="footer-wrap">
            <footer class="mate-jos">
                <h6 class="mate-jos-text">a</h6>
            </footer>
        </div>
    </section>
</div>
</body>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"
        integrity="sha256-3edrmyuQ0w65f8gfBsqowzjJe2iM6n0nKciPUp8y+7E="
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="js/js.js"></script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change position from `fixed` to `sticky` which is [not supported by IE Browsers](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sticky). If you do so, you have to move `<footer>` element outside `#footer-wrap`, see here: https://jsfiddle.net/kcxto9n0/1/

Or you can add `max-width: 1264px;` to `.mate-jos` which will also fix your problem, see here: https://jsfiddle.net/kcxto9n0/

Comment: If i change it to sticky, bottom: will not work anymore. max-width:1264 doesn't fix it either.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding reset `margin` and `padding` code in your CSS. Try adding this in your css file.

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the width in `.mate-jos` to `width: 1264px;` add

```
    #footer-wrap{
      position: relative;
      width: 100%;
      overflow: hidden;
    }
```

to your css like so

```css
        
        body {
            width: 100%;
            text-rendering: optimizeLegibility; /*setam textul sa fie optimzat pentru o lizbilitate mai buna, in detrimentul vitezei de incarcare si a preciziei geometrice*/
            font-weight: 200;
            font-size: 15px;
            overflow: hidden; /*dezactivam scrollbar-urile in cazul in care continutul depaseste "element's box"*/
            font-family: 'Proxima Nova';
            color: #fff;
            height: 100%;
        }
        
        @keyframes tranzitie-inceput {
            from {opacity: 0;}
            to {opacity: 1;}
        }
        
        #mate, #info {
          font-weight: bold;
          font-size: 5rem;
          text-transform: uppercase; /*transformam textul in MAJUSCULE*/
          text-align: center;
          background-color: #429ba8;
          height: 50%;
          position: relative;
        }
        
        #mate {
            border-bottom: 1px solid #D3D3D3; /*inseram un border gri, subtire, ce va avea efectul de umbra/diferentiere a celor 2 jumatati*/
        }
        
        #info {
           background-color: #87cebf;
        }
        
        #container-index {
            height: 100vh; /*div-ul container va fi egal cu toata inaltimea viewport-ului, ceea ce va face ca continutul sa fie la fel de mare ca suprafata vizibila a device-ului utilizatorului*/
            animation-name: tranzitie-inceput;
            animation-duration: 1s;
            user-select: none; /*dezactivam selectia utilizatorului*/
            cursor: pointer;
        }
        
        .text-mate {
            position: relative;
            top: 50%;
            transform: translateY(-50%);
            -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%); /*centram textul VERTICAL in interiorul parintelui #MATE*/
        }
        
        .text-info {
            position: relative;
            top: 50%;
            transform: translateY(-50%);
            -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%); /*centram textul VERTICAL in interiorul parintelui #INFO*/
        }
        
        .hover { /*pregatim clasa ce se va adauga div-ului peste care trecem cu mouse-ul, utilizand jQuery*/
            transition: 2.5s; /*folosim un efect incet in care elementul se mareste*/
            height: 75% !important;
        }
        
        .default { /*pregatim clasa ce se va adauga celuilalt div fata de cel pe care se trece mouse-ul, utilizand jQuery*/
            transition: 1.5s;
            height: 50% !important; /*folosim un efect rapid in care se va ajunge la forma initiala*/
        }
        
        .not-hovered-on { /*pregatim clasa ce se va adauga celuilalt div fata de cel pe care se trece mouse-ul, utilizand jQuery*/
            transition: 2.5s;
            height: 25% !important; /*folosim un efect incet in care elementul se micsoreaza*/
        }
        
        /*CSS PENTRU PAGINA-MATE.HTML*/
        /*CSS PENTRU PAGINA-MATE.HTML*/
        /*CSS PENTRU PAGINA-MATE.HTML*/
        /*CSS PENTRU PAGINA-MATE.HTML*/
        /*CSS PENTRU PAGINA-MATE.HTML*/
        /*CSS PENTRU PAGINA-MATE.HTML*/
        /*CSS PENTRU PAGINA-MATE.HTML*/
        
        #container-mate {
            background-color: #e6e7d0;
            height: 100vh; /*div-ul container va fi egal cu toata inaltimea viewport-ului, ceea ce va face ca continutul sa fie la fel de mare ca suprafata vizibila a device-ului utilizatorului*/
        }
        
        /*HEADER-UL PAGINII*/
        
        #meniu-mate {
            max-width: 1264px; /*meniul va fi MAXIM 1300px*/
            margin: 0 auto; /*meniul este centrat orizontal*/
            background-color: #fff;
            height: 100vh;
        }
        
        .mate-sus {
            height: 15vh; /*15% din viewport*/
            background: linear-gradient(to right, #7ec7bc, #429ba8);
        }
        
        .logo {
            float: right;
        }
        
        .selector-portal {
            height: 4vh;
            background: linear-gradient(to right, #9bddc5, #34bab8);
            margin-bottom: 2rem;
        }
        
        .selector-portal > ul {
                display: inline-block;
                position: relative;
                top: 50%;
                transform: translateY(-50%);
                margin-left: 1.5rem;
                font-size: 1.5rem;
        }
        
        .selector-portal > ul > li {
                display: inline;
        }
        
        .selector-portal > ul > li > a {
                text-decoration: none;
                color: #fff;
                font-style: italic;
        }
        
        /*CONTINUTUL PAGINII*/
        
        #cursuri-mate {
            height: 15%;
            max-width: 90%;
            margin: 0 auto;
            background-color: #429ba8;
            margin-bottom: 3.5rem;
        }
        
        .cursuri-text-mate {
            font-size: 4rem;
            position: relative;
            transform: translateY(-50%);
            top: 50%;
            margin-left: 4rem;
        }
        
        .fa-book {
            color: black;
            position: relative;
            transform: translateY(-50%);
            top: 50%;
            float: right;
            margin-right: 2rem;
        }
        
        #exercitii-mate {
            height: 15%;
            max-width: 90%;
            margin: 0 auto;
            background-color: #429ba8;
            margin-bottom: 3.5rem;
        }
        
        .exercitii-text-mate {
            font-size: 4rem;
            position: relative;
            transform: translateY(-50%);
            top: 50%;
            margin-left: 4rem;
        }
        
        .fa-pencil-alt-mate {
            color: black;
            position: relative;
            transform: translateY(-50%);
            top: 50%;
            float: right;
            margin-right: 2rem;
        }
        
        .fa-question {
            color: black;
            position: relative;
            transform: translateY(-50%);
            top: 50%;
            float: right;
            margin-right: 2rem;
        }
        
        #variante-mate {
            height: 15%;
            max-width: 90%;
            margin: 0 auto;
            background-color: #429ba8;
            margin-bottom: 3.5rem;
        }
        
        .variante-text-mate {
            font-size: 4rem;
            position: relative;
            transform: translateY(-50%);
            top: 50%;
            margin-left: 4rem;
        }
        
        .fa-pencil-alt {
            color: black;
            position: relative;
            transform: translateY(-50%);
            top: 50%;
            float: right;
            margin-right: 2rem;
        }
        
        /*FOOTER*/
        
        .mate-jos {
            background-color: #28494e;
            position: fixed;
            bottom: 0;
            width: 1264px;
            color: white;
            text-align: center;
        }
        
        .mate-jos-text {
        
        }
        
        #footer-wrap{
          position: relative;
          width: 100%;
          overflow: hidden;
        }
```

```html
        <html>
        <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8" />
            <link href="css/reset.css" rel="stylesheet" />
            <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
            <link href="css/fontawesome-all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
            <title>Portal Mate</title>
        </head>
        <body>
        <div id="container-mate">
            <section id="meniu-mate">
                <header class="mate-sus"><h1 class="logo">MATE-INFO || LOGO</h1></header>
                <nav class="selector-portal">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="portal-mate.html">mate</a></li>
                        <li><a href="portal-info.html">info</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
                <article id="cursuri-mate">
                    <i class="fas fa-book fa-6x"></i>
                    <h1 class="cursuri-text-mate">Cursuri</h1>
                </article>
                <article id="exercitii-mate">
                    <i class="fas fa-pencil-alt fa-6x"></i>
                    <h1 class="exercitii-text-mate">Exercitii</h1>
                </article>
                <article id="variante-mate">
                    <i class="fas fa-question fa-6x"></i>
                    <h1 class="variante-text-mate">Variante Bacalaureat</h1>
                </article>
                <div id="footer-wrap">
                    <footer class="mate-jos">
                        <h6 class="mate-jos-text">a</h6>
                    </footer>
                </div>
            </section>
        </div>
        </body>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"
                integrity="sha256-3edrmyuQ0w65f8gfBsqowzjJe2iM6n0nKciPUp8y+7E="
                crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="js/js.js"></script>
        </html>
```

Comment: It worked. But it isn't scalable (like #container is, because of max-width). I think I need to use max-width somehow.